# Docker build for desktop application

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, desktop-application, gitlab-ci

I have a desktop GUI application developed using (C++/ QT IFW). The repository for this application is in gitlab. Gitlab CI/CD is configured using gitlab-ci.yml file. The gitlab runner installed on windows server 2012, will build the desktop application. The output of the build (.exe application) is compressed to zip format and delivered to artifactory server. The end user downloads the artifact (.ZIP file) and installs the application on their Windows 7/10 system. Suppose, I want to build on new windows server 2016, I have to install all the build tools along with the gitlab runner. How can I use docker in this scenario? I want to use docker to create or reproduce build enviornment.

```
* Can I create a docker image for build tools?
* build the source code inside the docker container
*  upload to the artifactory server the output of build (.exe application) in compressed zip format.
* Deliver the compressed ZIP file for the end user via artifactory server
* The end user downloads the ZIP file from artifactory server and installs the tool on their local machine
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: "Demo Project"
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "true"
  REPOSITORY_NAME: "test" 
  ARTIFACTORY_ROOT_PATH: ""
  ARTIFACTORY_WEBSITE: ""
  ARTIFACTORY_USER: ""
  CURL: "C:\\build-tools\\curl\\bin\\curl.exe"
  JQ: "C:\\build-tools\\jq\\jq-win64.exe"
  TEMPFILE: "C:\\build-tools\\jq\\temp.txt" 
  REPLACE_VERSION_RELEASE_DATE: "C:\\build-tools\\ReplaceVersionReleasedate\\ReplaceVersionReleasedate.exe"
  ZIP: "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"
  QTIFW_REPOGEN: "c:\\QT\\QtIFW-3.0.4\\bin\\repogen"
  JFROG_CLI: "C:\\build-tools\\JFROG-CLI\\jfrog"
  JOM: "C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe"
before_script:
  - echo "starting build for %PROJECT_NAME%"
  - SET BUILDVER=%CI_COMMIT_TAG:~3%
  - set PATH=C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2015_64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC;%PATH%
  - call vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
stages:
  - build
  - deploy_rv
build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "Building (Release)..."
  - 'RMDIR /S /Q dist'
  - 'qmake test.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=release" "CONFIG+=qml_release"'
  - '%JOM% qmake_all'
  - '%JOM%'
  - '%JOM% install'
  - 'qmake test.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=release" "CONFIG+=qml_release"'
  - '%JOM% qmake_all'<
  - '%JOM%'
  - '%JOM% install'
  - 'MD dist\release_build\test_app'
  - echo "Copying files into build folder ..."
  - 'xcopy test_app\mlapp_redist\*.* dist\release_build\test_app /E /Y >NUL'

  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/

deploy_rv:
  stage: deploy_rv
  script:
  - echo "Deploy Artifact..."
  # Compress Artifact
  - '"%ZIP%" a test.rv.zip dist/'
  - '"%ZIP%" a test.rv-%BUILDVER%.zip dist/'

  # Configure JFrog CLI with parameters of your Artifactory instance
  - '%JFROG_CLI% rt config --url  %ARTIFACTORY_WEBSITE% --user %ARTIFACTORY_USER% --apikey %API_KEY%'

  - 'set mydate=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%'

  - '%JFROG_CLI% rt u "test.rv.zip" %ARTIFACTORY_ROOT_PATH%/tools/test/test.rv.zip --build-name=test.rv --build-number=%BUILDVER%  --props releasenote=%releasenote%;releaseversion=%BUILDVER%;releasedate=%mydate% --flat=false'
  - '%JFROG_CLI% rt u "test.rv-%BUILDVER%.zip" %ARTIFACTORY_ROOT_PATH%/tools/test/test.rv-%BUILDVER%.zip --build-name=test.rv-%BUILDVER% --build-number=%BUILDVER%  --props releasenote=%releasenote%;releaseversion=%BUILDVER%;releasedate=%mydate% --flat=false'

  #  Publish build info to Artifactory.
  - '%JFROG_CLI% rt bp test.rv %BUILDVER%'
  - '%JFROG_CLI% rt bp test.rv-%BUILDVER% %BUILDVER%'

  # Trigger to update other Repository
  - '%CURL% -X POST -F token=%My_TOKEN% -F ref=master -F "variables[RELEASE]=true" -F "variables[PROGRAM]=test" --insecure https://gitlab/project/trigger/pipeline'
  only:
  - /^(rv-)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+)$/
```

dockerfile

```
# Use the latest Windows Server Core image.
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression false

RUN powershell -Command \
    iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')); \
    choco feature disable --name showDownloadProgress

RUN choco install visualstudio2015professional
RUN choco install qtcreator
RUN choco install curl
RUN choco install jq
RUN choco install 7zip.install
RUN choco install jfrog-cli
RUN choco install jom
```

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with Qt, please avoid abusing the tags.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable overall approach.  Can you share what you've done so far and what problems you're running into?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. Please find the sample gitlab-ci.yml file and dockerfile. Should I include the rest of the script (Building the source code, zip the output of build and upload into artifactory) in dockerfile? How do I proceed further?

Comment: @DavidMaze How do I use the build tool image to build the script part? I want to run the build script inside build tool container